# Why did my vote hammer come up second on the list when I entered it in the input?

Tags: support, dupehammer

In regards to this question:

- [How to pass window.variable to a PHP variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46349389/how-to-pass-window-variable-to-a-php-variable)

Why did the following come up first in the list

- [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

when I specifically entered the following in the vote input to hammer it?

- [How to pass JavaScript variables to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)

Note: Yes, I know I can edit it after in order for it to be first.

There were 2 people who entered possible duplicates, but the one I chose was the most appropriate one in relation to the question.

The first possible duplicate was the one I used to hammer it, then someone else added the other one after.

**Note:** I have not altered the sequence for it, because I wanted people to see it, nor should it be modified by anyone please.

I thought for a moment that it might have something to do with the amount of answers given, yet the one I chose has 12 answers, when the first on the list has only 4.

Comment: Ok, I think I know what happened. This seems to be related to the amount of votes the questions received.

Comment: I'm not convinced that there's a lot of need to worry about the order of the questions in the duplicate closure list.  There are other things of more importance for The Team to work on.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, I know there are things more important than this. However I feel this was a particular case where the (2nd) duplicate placed after the first one by another member wasn't as relevant as the one I chose to hammer it with. If one is better than the other and better answers the question, then the one I chose should have been placed as the first one on top.

Comment: Given you as a Mjolnir can rearrange the list as you deem fit anyways, I don't think this is a huge problem. It's not much work after all.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I didn't say it was a problem, I asked "why" this was. Please read the question again.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I did read the question, and I never claimed you said it's a problem. I just wanted to state that I think it doesn't matter. Also note that this was not an attempt to answer your questions *"why?"*, hence I posted it as a comment and not as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answers show up in the order in which they had duplicate votes cast for them.  You cast your duplicate vote for that question after the other question had a duplicate vote cast using it.

Comment: Yeah, it just dawned on me and posted a comment under my question about it after seeing the links at the right after; I didn't see your answer when I wrote it. I'll accept the answer in good time, thanks.

Comment: Thing is though; wouldn't it make more sense that the hammer would override the sequence, as I entered it in the input myself?

Comment: @Fred-ii- You're more than welcome to propose that in a feature request if you want.  Make sure to justify why you think that would be beneficial in the proposal.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll get one ready at a later time and will see what the response will be, *cheers*